# Getting the dimensions of a rendered text in Cimg library

Tags: c++, cimg

I have an image of a rectangle, and I need to draw the rectangle's dimensions in it. Now I want to find out the size of a text I'm about to draw so that I can determine an appropriate font size, as to make sure the text does not go outside of the rectangles boundaries, but also not unnecessarily small. I was using this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363908/Simple-two-file-graphics-library-for-C-Cplusplus library before but it as a bit to restricted in it's use, but it did have a function

```
int ezd_text_size( HEZDFONT x_hFont, const char *x_pText, int x_nTextLen, int *pw, int *ph )
```

Which given a font and a char* will calculate the length and width of the area the drawn text would require. I cannot find anything similar in the Cimg documentation though.

So does someone have experience with this issue using Cimg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to use method `CImg<T>::draw_text()` to draw your text on a `CImg<T>` image.
In that case, you have the possibility to call `draw_text()`on an empty instance, it will automatically set the image size to the minimal bounding box containing your text. Thus, the `width()` and `height()` of the resulting image gives you what you are looking for.

```
CImg<unsigned char> imgtext;
unsigned char color = 1;
imgtext.draw_text(0,0,"Hello guys !",&color,0,1,23);  // Draw with font height 23.
// Now, imgtext.width() and imgtext.height() gives you the dimensions you want.
```

It's easy then to check if the text fits your box size, and eventually reduce the font size until it does.